# I want to show two accordions in a Material UI table body

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, accordion

I'm trying to integrate Material-UI's Accordion component inside a table to display transaction data. Specifically, I want to have two accordions: "Pending" and "Posted". The idea is that clicking on each accordion will expand or collapse the table rows associated with that category.

However, I'm facing an issue where the Accordion only spans the first column of the table. I've managed to make the Accordion span all the columns using the colSpan attribute, but the data/content inside the Accordion does not span across all columns. Instead, it's confined to the first column.

Here is the [link to CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-monad-pt8hjv?file=/src/App.js) for what I have tried and what it looks like right now.

Someone posted [this answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64988164/add-table-row-data-within-the-material-ui-accordion) but it still has the same problem that I am facing.

This is what I want it to look like. Clicking the "Pending" and "Posted" would expand/collapse the respective transactions  [Image link](https://ibb.co/k92Lh6K)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this. I'm also having trouble to get Accordion to work inside MUI Table.

Comment: @Organic unfortunately, I didn't.